# String in list but not showing up with index method in Python

Tags: python, string, list, parsing, search

I have a 2 lists that I made from reading a txt file. 1 list contains codes for items and the other list contains the corresponding prices. I'm trying to get the user to enter a code, then search the code list for that code and print the corresponding price with this code:

```
while code != "9999":
    code = input("Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: ")

    if code in priceNumList:
        y = priceList.index(code)
        print("Item found: ", priceList[y])

    elif code not in priceNumList:
        print("Item not found.")
```

Whenever I run this and enter a code that is in the list, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jeste/Documents/Python Projects/Homework/wakemart.py", line 
36, in <module>
    y = priceList.index(code)
ValueError: '####' is not in list
```

I am certain that the price codes I am entering are an EXACT match to the elements in my list, yet the program tells me it's not in there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out! the problem was "y = priceList.index(code)" should have been "y = priceNumList.index(code)" That's what I get for making two lists! :P